# How do you pass a CommandArgument to a popup in DotNetNuke

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke-6

I have an edit command that needs to be passed to the popup edit window in dotnetnuke.

So far my code reflects older versions of dotnetnuke that do not support the popup windows.

```
  Response.Redirect(EditUrl(string.Empty, string.Empty, "Edit", "tid=" + e.CommandArgument));
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you can turn popup off in site settings

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how the new popups should work:

[dotnetnuke.com/forums](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/203/threadid/433235/scope/posts.aspx)

It SHOULD work like you can see in the forum thread but in my case its not working I dont know why (I have to have a closer look at this problem).
As parameters you can use the string[] as in the past and read out the parameters in your editcontrol with the following code:

```
string smyTestParameter = Page.Request["myTestParameter"];
```

I hope this helps.

best regards, noone.